# Is there a way to make 2 very similar pieces of code into a function and repeat?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have 2 really similar pieces of code that I would like to put in a code to prevent repeating myself multiple times

This is for my new class assignment so I wonder if you all would know. I've tried to put some values in the parameters but it didn't work.

```
pizzaType1 = {
    "Hawaiian":"$8.50", "Pepperoni":"$8.50", "Simply Cheese":"$8.50", "Ham & Cheese":"$8.50", "Beef & Onion":"$8.50", "Cheesy Garlic":"$8.50", "BBQ Pork & Onion":"$8.50"
    }
pizzaType2 = {
    "Mr. Wedge":"$13.50", "Apricot Chicken":"$13.50", "Cranberry & Chicken":"$13.50", "BBQ Meatlovers":"$13.50", "Godfather":"$13.50"
    }

for x,y in pizzaType1.items():
    print(x,y)
for x,y in pizzaType2.items():
    print(x,y)
```

This is the code I would like to put in a function

Comment: Show what you have tried (as properly formatted text in the question).

Comment: Are you just trying to trade the two `for loops` in for one function?

Comment: yes @MarkMeyer I think that is what I'm trying to do

Comment: Well, what's different about the two loops?  They each refer to a different `dict`.  So that's your function parameter.  Pass in a `dict`, then print the items in the `dict` that was passed.  That's your function.  It takes a single `dict` argument.  You can call it `d` or something (don't call it `dict`).

Comment: I don't know how to do that which is the problem.. @TomKarzes

Comment: Just use `def print_dict(d):` then put one of the loops in the function body, indented, using `d` for the `dict` name.  Then you can call `print_dict` to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're going for, but I'm not sure:

```
pizzaType1 = {
    "Hawaiian":"$8.50", "Pepperoni":"$8.50", "Simply Cheese":"$8.50", "Ham & Cheese":"$8.50", "Beef & Onion":"$8.50", "Cheesy Garlic":"$8.50", "BBQ Pork & Onion":"$8.50"
    }
pizzaType2 = {
    "Mr. Wedge":"$13.50", "Apricot Chicken":"$13.50", "Cranberry & Chicken":"$13.50", "BBQ Meatlovers":"$13.50", "Godfather":"$13.50"
    }

def print_items(dictionary): # make our function
    for x, y in dictionary.items():
        print(x,y)

print_items(pizzaType1) # use our function
print_items(pizzaType2)
```

Output:

```
Hawaiian $8.50
Beef & Onion $8.50
Pepperoni $8.50
Simply Cheese $8.50
Cheesy Garlic $8.50
BBQ Pork & Onion $8.50
Ham & Cheese $8.50
Mr. Wedge $13.50
Apricot Chicken $13.50
Godfather $13.50
BBQ Meatlovers $13.50
Cranberry & Chicken $13.50
```

Comment: It's generally frowned upon to outright post homework solutions.

Comment: lmao anyways thanks I'll tick ur answer once 4 mins are over :)

Comment: @Reedinationer The opposite of "sarcastic and not helpful comments" is not outright homework solutions. I think it would be better to leave helpful comments of reminder on such homework questions. Also, a tag badge is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Reedinationer If your primary motivation for posting solutions is to get badges, then you probably shouldn't be here.  Your primary motivation *should* be to help people.  And in the case of homework questions, that doesn't mean posting complete solutions.